# Как откатиться до php 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx

Для работоспособности сайта необходимы версии php 5.6 и mysql 5.6
Изначально php был 5.6, но в процессе установки php-fpm он обновился до 7.2
Теперь, пытаясь откатиться до 5.6 по мануалам из интернета ничего не выходит:
5.6 версия уже скачана, как и php-fpm

[Вот что происходит при вводе некоторым команд](https://pastebin.com/qv7a043Z):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:8 http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://ams2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

$ sudo apt-get purge php *
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bin
E: Unable to locate package boot
E: Unable to locate package dev
E: Unable to locate package etc
E: Unable to locate package home
E: Unable to locate package initrd.img
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'initrd.img'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'initrd.img'
E: Unable to locate package initrd.img.old
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'initrd.img.old'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'initrd.img.old'
E: Unable to locate package lib
E: Unable to locate package lib64
E: Unable to locate package lost+found
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lost+found'
E: Unable to locate package media
E: Unable to locate package mnt
E: Unable to locate package proc
E: Unable to locate package root
E: Unable to locate package run
E: Unable to locate package sbin
E: Unable to locate package srv
E: Unable to locate package sys
E: Unable to locate package tmp
E: Unable to locate package usr
E: Unable to locate package var
E: Unable to locate package vmlinuz
E: Unable to locate package vmlinuz.old
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'vmlinuz.old'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'vmlinuz.old'
```

А так же нужно откатиться до mysql 5.6, сейчас 5.7

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu/dists/ . видите каталог bionic? и я — нет. не собирал ваш ondrej пакетов под эту версию дистрибутива.

Comment: Не `php *`, а `php*` конечно же

Comment: Таки у вас trusty или bionic?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я понятия не имею что это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 определитесь с версией ос

```
lsb_release -a
```

интересует строка Codename

скорее всего у вас там bionic

если bionic следуем дальше по мануалу, если нет уточните кодовое имя или версию

2 приведите sources.list к нормальному виду, лучше к исходному
  чистый sources.list https://gist.github.com/jackw1111/d31140946901fab417131ff4d9ae92e3
  так же удалите лишние репы из /etc/apt/sources.list.d

3 php

```
apt purge php*
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6
```

все расширения так же должны будут ставиться с префиксом php5.6

4 mysql, сразу отмечу что не рекомендовал бы понижать версию mysql до 5.6, но если очень хотите, то делаете на свой страх и риск следующее:

скачиваете DEB Bundle с https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html#downloads

```
tar -xf mysql-server_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
```

поочередно устанавливаете deb пакеты

```
sudo dpkg -i имя пакета
```

необходимы:

1. libmysqlclient18_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
2. libmysqlclient-dev_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
3. libmysqld-dev_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
4. mysql-client_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
5. mysql-common_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
6. mysql-community-server_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
7. mysql-server_5.6.42-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb

порядок может быть чуть другой, если что, установка укажет на это

в случае ошибок зависимостей выполните apt install -f

---

PS а вообще лучше использовать более старую версию убунты в вашем случае